# Steps to Create a copy of a Drupal 7 website using cpanel?

Tags: 7

I want to create an exact copy of an existing drupal 7 website in a subdomain. What steps should I take to do this using just cpanel?

Comment: Did you install Drupal via Fantastico or cPanel?

Comment: As side note, you are using a unregistered account, which is valid just on a single computer, and a single browser. If you are using an unregistered account with more browsers, or more computers, you are using different accounts, not the same accounts. If you need to use more than one computer, or browser, consider registering an account by adding an [OpenID account](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent), or you will not able to comment on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I would take in cloning the site. First, Create the subdomain. Then copy all the files from the live site to the subdomain. Then I would back up the database. Create a new database and import the backup into that. Assign the user from the first database to the second one. Then change the settings.php file to read from the second database. Also, if you have a base url set in settings.php you would need to change that as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: If the original site is live, I would put in maintenance mode first.

Answer (score 0):

if the site is coming from another cpanel, there are export/import features for entire sites.

otherwise there's no cpanel specific way to move a drupal site that I am aware of.